# How can i show image on device on ionic

Tags: image, ionic-framework, device, show

I don't show image in ionic page. Image is visible when test in browser with "ionic serve" but not visible on device or on emulator. I know this is most basic feature but i don't it. I get data as json from api and put publicContents variable. I share html code, json data and screenshots.  I have a this problem. How can i do?

page.html:

```
<ion-card (click)="readContent(content)" *ngFor="let content of publicContents">
    <img data-src="{{ content['imageUrls'][0] }}" > 
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>
        <a href="{{ content['imageUrls'][0] }}">{{ content['imageUrls'][0] }}</a> {{ content.name_basic }}  
      </ion-card-title>
      <p [innerHtml]="content.summary"> </p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

publicContents:

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name_basic": "Ünlüler, İzmir'e yardım akımı başlattı",
    "summary": "<p>İzmir Büyükşehir Belediye Başkanı Tunç Soyer yaptığı açıklamada, depremde zarar gören yapılarla ilgili yaptığı açıklamada 7 binanın acilen yıkılması gerektiğini söyledi.</p>",
    "content": "<p>İzmir Büyükşehir Belediyesi Başkanı Tunç Soyer, meydana gelen depremin ardından açıklama yaptı.</p><p><br></p><p>7 binanın yıkıldığını, 504 binanın da hasarlı olduğunu açıklayan Soyer, 92 kişinin yaşamını yitirdiğini 994 yurttaşın da yaralandığını söyledi.</p><p><br></p><p><strong>GÖNÜLLÜ SAYISI GİTTİKÇE ARTIYOR</strong></p><p>6 bin 224 belediye personelinin çalışmalarda görev aldığını kaydeden İzmir Belediye Başkanı, gönüllülerin sayısının ise her saat arttığı için net bir sayının olmadığını ifade etti.</p><p><br></p><p><strong>\"7 BİNANIN ACİL YIKILMASI GEREKİYOR\"</strong></p><p><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi.</span></p><p><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><br></span></p><p><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi.</span></p><p><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal;\"><br></span></p><p><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal;\"><br></span></p>",
    "images": "[{\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"2_3.jpg\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}, {\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"3_3.jpg\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}, {\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"4.1_1.jpg\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}]",
    "user_id": "Ana Yönetici",
    "updated_at": "2020-11-02 23:31:49",
    "_is_restorable": false,
    "_is_deletable": false,
    "_is_editable": false,
    "_is_showable": false,
    "_is_exportable": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name_basic": "Fransa, ülkede faaliyet gösteren Ülkü Ocakları'nı kapatma kararı aldı",
    "summary": "<p>İzmir Büyükşehir Belediye Başkanı Tunç Soyer yaptığı açıklamada, depremde zarar gören yapılarla ilgili yaptığı açıklamada 7 binanın acilen yıkılması gerektiğini söyledi.</p>",
    "content": "<p>İzmir Büyükşehir Belediyesi Başkanı Tunç Soyer, meydana gelen depremin ardından açıklama yaptı.</p><p><br></p><p>7 binanın yıkıldığını, 504 binanın da hasarlı olduğunu açıklayan Soyer, 92 kişinin yaşamını yitirdiğini 994 yurttaşın da yaralandığını söyledi.</p><p><br></p><p><strong>GÖNÜLLÜ SAYISI GİTTİKÇE ARTIYOR</strong></p><p>6 bin 224 belediye personelinin çalışmalarda görev aldığını kaydeden İzmir Belediye Başkanı, gönüllülerin sayısının ise her saat arttığı için net bir sayının olmadığını ifade etti.</p><p><br></p><p><strong>\"7 BİNANIN ACİL YIKILMASI GEREKİYOR\"</strong></p><p><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi.</span></p><p><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><br></span></p><p><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi.</span></p><p><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal;\"><br></span></p><p><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal;\"><br></span></p>",
    "images": "[{\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"2_2.jpg\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}, {\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"3.1.png\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}, {\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"3_2.jpg\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}]",
    "user_id": "Ana Yönetici",
    "updated_at": "2020-11-02 23:30:54",
    "_is_restorable": false,
    "_is_deletable": false,
    "_is_editable": false,
    "_is_showable": false,
    "_is_exportable": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name_basic": "ABD'de anketlere göre Biden, Trump'ın önünde",
    "summary": "<p>İzmir Büyükşehir Belediye Başkanı Tunç Soyer yaptığı açıklamada, depremde zarar gören yapılarla ilgili yaptığı açıklamada 7 binanın acilen yıkılması gerektiğini söyledi.</p>",
    "content": "<p>İzmir Büyükşehir Belediyesi Başkanı Tunç Soyer, meydana gelen depremin ardından açıklama yaptı.</p><p><br></p><p>7 binanın yıkıldığını, 504 binanın da hasarlı olduğunu açıklayan Soyer, 92 kişinin yaşamını yitirdiğini 994 yurttaşın da yaralandığını söyledi.</p><p><br></p><p><strong>GÖNÜLLÜ SAYISI GİTTİKÇE ARTIYOR</strong></p><p>6 bin 224 belediye personelinin çalışmalarda görev aldığını kaydeden İzmir Belediye Başkanı, gönüllülerin sayısının ise her saat arttığı için net bir sayının olmadığını ifade etti.</p><p><br></p><p><strong>\"7 BİNANIN ACİL YIKILMASI GEREKİYOR\"</strong></p><p><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi.</span></p><p><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><br></span></p><p><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi.</span></p><p><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal;\"><br></span></p><p><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal;\"><br></span></p>",
    "images": "[{\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"2.1.png\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}, {\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"2_1.jpg\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}, {\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"3_1.jpg\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}]",
    "user_id": "Ana Yönetici",
    "updated_at": "2020-11-02 23:29:36",
    "_is_restorable": false,
    "_is_deletable": false,
    "_is_editable": false,
    "_is_showable": false,
    "_is_exportable": false
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name_basic": "Tunç Soyer: 7 binanın acilen yıkılması gerekiyor",
    "summary": "<p>İzmir Büyükşehir Belediye Başkanı Tunç Soyer yaptığı açıklamada, depremde zarar gören yapılarla ilgili yaptığı açıklamada 7 binanın acilen yıkılması gerektiğini söyledi.</p>",
    "content": "<p>İzmir Büyükşehir Belediyesi Başkanı Tunç Soyer, meydana gelen depremin ardından açıklama yaptı.</p><p><br></p><p>7 binanın yıkıldığını, 504 binanın da hasarlı olduğunu açıklayan Soyer, 92 kişinin yaşamını yitirdiğini 994 yurttaşın da yaralandığını söyledi.</p><p><br></p><p><strong>GÖNÜLLÜ SAYISI GİTTİKÇE ARTIYOR</strong></p><p>6 bin 224 belediye personelinin çalışmalarda görev aldığını kaydeden İzmir Belediye Başkanı, gönüllülerin sayısının ise her saat arttığı için net bir sayının olmadığını ifade etti.</p><p><br></p><p><strong>\"7 BİNANIN ACİL YIKILMASI GEREKİYOR\"</strong></p><p><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi.</span></p><p><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\"><br></span></p><p><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi. </span><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\">Depremin etkilediği bölgelerle ilgili açıklamalarına devam eden Soyer, \"Düne kadar bin 428 arama kurtarma personeli vardı. Bu rakam bin 784'e çıktı. 397 bina az hasarlı. 42 ağır hasar. 7 binanın da acil yıkılması gerekiyor.\" dedi.</span></p><p><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal;\"><br></span></p><p><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal;\"><br></span></p>",
    "images": "[{\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"1.1.jpg\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}, {\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"2.jpg\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}, {\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"3.jpg\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}, {\"disk\": \"fileServer\", \"file_name\": \"4.1.jpg\", \"destination_path\": \"2020/11/02/\"}]",
    "user_id": "Ana Yönetici",
    "updated_at": "2020-11-02 23:26:21",
    "_is_restorable": false,
    "_is_deletable": false,
    "_is_editable": false,
    "_is_showable": false,
    "_is_exportable": false
  }
]
```

[browser ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehsiD.jpg):

[emulator ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmFii.png):

Comment: Have you tried using [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)? There might be errors or warnings in the console that can help find the problem.

Comment: Yes i try with android stdio but not find any log about this problem :/

Comment: I'm not sure if Android Studio shows webview logs, it's possible it doesn't (or maybe not by default). I suggest trying remote debugging with Chrome. And if there are still no errors you can inspect the specific `img` element and check its `src`, size, position etc.

Comment: thank you Thomas i will try